# MVC Authorization Role and IPrincipal - how does it work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, iprincipal

I've managed to successfully implement a custom MembershipProvider for my MVC2 application. I have my own User table as well as Role table.

My problem right now is that when I put in the [Authorize(Roles="blah")] attribute, it doesn't work. I've searched a bit but haven't found a definitive answer I'm looking for, which is -- how does this Role authorization work? My web.config uses the standard AspNet role provider.

My understanding is that I have to have my User.cs class implement the IPrincipal interface, which means, adding the code to check for IsInRole.

My question(s) -- is this correct? How does the framework know to and know how to get my custom User object? My understanding is that the Asp.Net authentication & authorization pieces work with MembershipUser.

Any tips, thoughts, or links would be greatly appreciated,
Thx

Comment: I am not sure how this works with MVC, however in ASP.NET & WCF you'd do something along the lines of:[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "RoleName")] instead of [Authorize(Roles="RoleName")]

Answer (score 1):

Is your roles table / code an implementation of a RoleProvider?  I believe the IPrincipal works against the default RoleProvider as configured in the web.config.

This [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1101402/2025628.aspx#2025628) talks about what you would need to do in order to implement your own IPrincipal, if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out, I'm just a little blind.

Since I created my own custom MembershipProvider (with its own custom User table AND Role table), it only stands to reason that I had to implement a custom RoleProvider. So, once I did that, it all makes sense, because the RoleProvider has the IsUserInRole method, i.e.

```
public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        IUserRepository userRepository = GetUserRepository();
        User user = userRepository.Retrieve(username);

        // and here, my User class implements IPrincipal
        if (user != null && user.IsInRole(roleName)) 
                return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```